# nuxt,js facing issues to get data inside vuetify table

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

im facing issues  to get data inside vuetify table, i check my API in postman it working perfect. when tried to display data in vuetify it not showing and it not showing any errors.

**Laravel API Controller**

```
public function businesslist() {
      $businesslist = Business::paginate(2)->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      return response($businesslist);
    }
}
```

**MY Laravel API**

```
Route::get('/Businessregisterlist', 'BusinessController@userlist')->name('businesslist');
```

**MY Nuxt.js vue page**

> ```
> <template>
>   <v-card>
>     <v-card-title>
>       Nutrition
>       <v-spacer></v-spacer>
>       <v-text-field
>         v-model="search"
>         append-icon="mdi-magnify"
>         label="Search"
>         single-line
>         hide-details
>       ></v-text-field>
>     </v-card-title>
>     <v-data-table
>       :headers="headers"
>       :items="registerlist"
>       :search="search"
>     ></v-data-table>
>   </v-card>
> </template><script>
>  import axios from 'axios';
>   export default {
>     data() {
>       return {
>         registerlist: [],
>                 headers: [
>     
>           { text: 'SL,No', value: 'name' },
>           { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
>           { text: 'Mobile  ', value: 'mobile_number' },
>           { text: 'Location  ', value: 'location' },
>           { text: 'Join Date  ', value: 'registration_date' },
>           { text: 'Renewal Date  ', value: 'registration_renewal_date' },
>         ],
>         registerlist: [
>           
>         ],
>       }
>     },
>     created: function () {
>         this.fetchData();
>     },
>      methods: {
>     fetchData: function () {
>         axios.get('/Businessregisterlist')
>       .then(res => this.registerlist = res.data.registerlist)
>  }
>     },
>    
>   }
>
>  </script>
> ```

Comment: try to `console.log(res.data)` to see if you get response data

Comment: @Jazuly i don't get any response data

Comment: so in that case the problem is in your backend, try to `dd($businesslist)` to see the data..

Comment: @Jazuly i dabble checked with Postman my backend working fine

Comment: i see, the problem is in you vue the url is `/Businessregisterlist` but on backend url is `/businesslist`

Comment: @Jazuly sorry i posted wrong url in question but im using this only /Businessregisterlist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222929/discussion-between-user12380208-and-jazuly).

Comment: @Jazuly im getting this error in console createError.js?2d83:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:69)

Comment: not sure with the error, can you share json result?

Comment: @Jazuly from postman json result right

Comment: @Jazuly i get data in console using this console.log(res.data)